# Subdomain overwiting CodeIgniter session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, authentication

I have 2 CodeIgniter installations, 1 on mydomain.com another on sub.mydomain.com.

I am trying to get sub.mydomain.com to be able to access the CI session created by mydomain.com. I have edited the cookie section of both config files to:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = ".mydomain.com";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Now if I go to mydomain.com setting the session and then go to sub.mydomain.com it seems to overwrite the session with a new one rather than being able to read from the existing session.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have same `$config['cookie_domain']    = ".mydomain.com";` on both configuration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was driving me crazy for hours but the solution (as usual) was simple. I had forgotten to make sure

```
$config[‘encryption_key’]
```

was the same for both applications!

Working great now

Comment: I'm using alias so `encryption_key` is 100% the same, but I have the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853783/codigniter-share-session-with-subdomain-sess-time-to-update