# How to carry codeigniter session in domain alias?

Tags: codeigniter, session-state

I have two urls pointing to one application e.g

```
api.mysite.com & alias.mysite.com
```

Even if I set config:
    $config['cookie_domain']    = ".mysite.com";

The session isn't carried over. I'm using the alias.mysite.com if the url will be seen by viewers via address bar when they are redirected after processing instead of having them see api.mysite.com

Appreciate any help or idea.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can find your answer here:

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/57101/

[Subdomain overwiting CodeIgniter session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881092/subdomain-overwiting-codeigniter-session)

[sharing session over subdomains in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318492/sharing-session-over-subdomains-in-php)

Comment: Thanks but my case was different. I've read all the links above before posting here at SO. I also tried their suggestions hence the config setup... They were talking about multiple apps in same server... I have a single app where two urls are pointed.